# jQuery how to select an element based on the random content of any attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've the following mark-up. I want to match the anchor tag based on the part of the URL.

Actually I've markup as below. And i know the sorting field name. I want to select the anchor based on the field name eg. `sort:resource_locator` based on this I want to select the first anchor tag and I want to give the class as per the direction such that it will add an small `up/down` arrow to it.

```
<th><a href="/sme_leads/index/page:1/sort:resource_locator/direction:asc">Resource Locator</a></th>
<th><a href="/sme_leads/index/page:1/sort:business_name/direction:asc">Business Name</a></th>
```

I want to know how can I select the anchor tag based on the `sort:resource_locator` information.

I know `$ and ^` for end and start respectively.

Comment: you want to add the class/arrow when the user clicks on the anchor? or just on document load?

Comment: does this need to be dynamic, or ONLY for sort:resource_locator

Comment: I know this from server side and I can pass it to javascript. It can be any field in my table head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Attribute Contains Selector `[name*="value"]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/):

```
$('a[href*="sort:resource_locator"]')
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CrCr3/)**.

Answer (score 2):

To select those `a` elements with a `sort:` in their `href`:

```
$('a').filter(
    function(){
        return this.href.indexOf('sort:') !== -1;
    });
```

To assign a class based on the string following the `direction:` string (`asc` or `desc`):

```
$('a').filter(
    function(){
        return this.href.indexOf('sort:') !== -1;
    }).addClass(
        function(){
            var href = this.href,
                matches = href.match(/direction\:([a-z]+)/);
            return matches[1];
        });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pgXVs/1/).